# Why do Random Walks always get back in 2D but not 3d?

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk, random

I'm aware that Random Walks always end up where it started in 2D but not in 3D. All the videos online are simulation-based, but does anyone know what the mathematical proof is?

Comment: The name is Polya's recurrence theorem. This should give you something to google. Also, the claim isn't that this happens *always*, only that it does so with probability 1.

Comment: Thank you! I'll research it.